# Reference for convergence properties of the Hausdorff distance

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces

Consider the following properties of the Hausdorff distance in $\mathbb R^n$.

1. Let $\Omega_n \supset \Omega_{n+1} \supset ...$ a sequence of open, convex and bounded sets with $\operatorname{int}(\bigcap \Omega_n)  \neq \emptyset$. Then $\Omega_n \rightarrow  \operatorname{int}(\bigcap \Omega_n)$ in the Hausdorff distance.
2. If $K_n$ is a sequence of compact sets converging in the Hausdorff distance to a compact set $K$, then for each $x \in \partial K$ exists a sequence $x_n \in \partial K_n$ that converges to $x$.

Times ago I found on the internet the proof of the above properties in a lecture note. But now the site does not exists and I am not finding a book with these properties. Someone could point me a book with the properties above?

Comment: Do you need a book to cite these results, or are you interested in proofs? There's a good chance those proofs in lecture notes were written *ad hoc*, not copied from any book. Part 2 in particular  follows quickly from the definition of Hausdorff metric combined with the definition of boundary point.

Comment: You might get something goolging these phrases together: "convex geometry" "Hausdorff metric" "basic results"

Comment: Hi Thursday, I am interessed in the two things. Thanks for your commentary